# c# O365 ews authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, exchangewebservices

I am trying to test our security setup re: Basic Authentication using c# EWS.

I am using the following lines to connect

```
ExchangeService myService = new ExchangeService(); 
myService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userData.EmailAddress, userData.Password);
```

Am I correct in assuming that this is Basic Authentication and not Modern Authentication

Comment: Its is using Basic Auth because your not using OAuth token. You might want to consider switch your code to use oAuth instead as Basic Auth is going away in 2020

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass url along with credentials as well,

```
ExchangeService myService = new ExchangeService()
{
   Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password),
   Url = new Uri(exchangeUrl)
};
```

or if you want to use particular exchange version then you can use like,

```
var exchangeVersion = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2; // or any valid version

ExchangeService myService = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion)
{
   Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password),
   Url = new Uri(exchangeUrl)
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mabiyan.
My code is working fine. I want to understand if it is using basic or modern authentication.
What do you think?

Comment: That is just a basic authentication, here is ms doc for more info [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange)